# How to deploy any module of prism application?

Tags: wpf, module, clickonce, prism

In my application i have more then 10 modules now once i  publish the application using clickonce after that i want to publish those modules which are changes..
Basically i do not want to publish whole application again as it takes lot of time and load on my server ..
but do not know how can i achive this...
i have also looked at 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/gg405497%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx

but doesn't help me...

Answer (score 1):

We have our modules stored on a network share with version information and permissions held in the database, we have a small utility app to manage and update these modules.

When the app starts (in Bootstrapper) it checks for modules you have permission to and versions using a shared service (IModuleService) then simply copies over any new or updated dlls into the local module directory - ready to be loaded by custom implementation of `DirectoryModuleCatalog`